# print an unknown matrix using java

Tags: java

I want to print an unknown matrix using java.

It is my code help me please

thank you

```
public static void PrintMAtrix(int[][] a) {
        
        for(int i=0;i< ;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem in your code? Do you get an error or unexpected result?

Comment: Your first FOR loop is incomplete. "i" is less than what?

Comment: That is my question

Comment: I don't know less than what it must be.

Comment: @Amir In words, what is the first loop doing?

Comment: It is counting Rows.

Comment: @Amir And a row is in `a[i]`, right? So how do you find out how many rows are in `a`?

Comment: yes this is my question `a[i].length` is `a[i]` columns

Comment: `a[i].length` is the length of the ith row, or in other words the number of columns in the ith row. On the other hand, `a.length` is the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to realize that `a` is an array of arrays. You are already using this fact when you do `a[i].length`. Here `a[i]` is one of the rows in the matrix and you need to determine how many columns it has. So to find the number of rows, you just do `a.length`.

Comment: You are the Best

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void PrintMAtrix(int[][] a) {

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j < a[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

You were missing in the first loop the length of the array so that it can loop over all the rows.

Edit:
Never mind about the missing new line you added it in an edit :)

Comment: So do you mean `a.length` is the number of `a` rows ?

Comment: @Amir Yes it is.

Comment: @Amir yes `a.length` gets the length of the array holding the rows, cause essentially, it is a array of arrays. so `a.length` gets you the number of rows, then `a[i].length` gets you the length of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can print matrix in one line, using `streams`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = new int[5][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = j;
        }
    }

    Arrays.stream(a).forEach(row -> {
        Arrays.stream(row).forEach(rowElement -> System.out.print(rowElement + " "));
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement this yourself how about using

```
public static void printMatrix(int[][] a) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
```

with `new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}` will print

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```